# Can a digital system be considered an ASIC regardless its physical implementation?

Tags: fpga, terminology, programmable-logic, asic

From my knowledge from classical books of computational and digital systems, an ASIC is a category of full-customized or semi-customized integrated circuit (IC) tailored to a specific application.

Then, off-the-shelf ICs, such as an FPGAs, would not be an ASIC since it can be reprogrammed many times to perform different functions and can be used for a wide variety of applications. Nevertheless, I've read that FPGA can be considered a "reprogrammed ASIC" if it used to perform a specific task.

Is there a ambiguity over the expression ASIC? Or programmable devices (such as a PLDs, microcontrollers, etc...) cannot be considered an ASIC regardless which task it is performing?

Comment: Had you looked at Internet resources like the [Wikipedia ASIC article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit) before posting this question? That starts with "*An ASIC is an integrated circuit (IC) chip customized for a particular use, rather than intended for general-purpose use*" and "*FPGAs are the modern-day technology improvement on breadboards, meaning that they are not made to be application-specific as opposed to ASICs.*". I think that and the rest of the article answers your question well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a ambiguity over the expression ASIC?

No. There isn't any ambiguity in practical usage.

> Can a digital system be considered an ASIC regardless its physical implementation?

What it really comes down to is money: specifically whether you need a custom mask for the silicon or not.

> I've read that FPGA can be considered a "reprogrammed ASIC

You should disregard that statement. It doesn't follow convention. That said, an FPGA for a specified task is probably the closest thing you will get to an ASIC without actually being an ASIC since it has the least extraneous hardware involved in performing the task. The difference between what is and is not an ASIC is much more distinct than the difference between something like a processor and a DSP, and perhaps even a GPU.

Answer (score 0):

ASIC stands for "Application Specific Integrated Circuit".  If all integrated circuits were ASICs, then the term "ASIC" would be a useless distinction, and you would simply use the term "integrated circuit".

The key thing that makes an ASIC and ASIC is some sort of silicon-level customization for a specific product.  There has to be some sort of communication that takes place between the higher-level product design team and the chip design team.  Additionally, since they are customized for a specific product, ASICs are not going to be available on the open market and there will not be any kind of documentation or even marketing brochures and such available.  The whole point of an ASIC is that the ASIC itself is not the product, it's simply a component in a larger system.  So, if there is a datasheet, it's probably not an ASIC.  If it's listed on digikey, it's probably not an ASIC.  If there are marketing brochures for the chip, it's probably not an ASIC.  If you can buy development boards for the chip, it's probably not an ASIC.  FPGAs fail all of these tests - they are available on the open market along with dev boards, documentation, brochures, white papers, etc.

I would say that it's possible for an FPGA to be considered an ASIC if it meets this criteria, but this is definitely not the case for FPGAs in general.  It's also not uncommon for an ASIC to contain one or more eFPGAs (embedded FPGA).

Now, the reason you might read that an FPGA can be considered a "reprogrammed ASIC" is because it's not uncommon to use an FPGA instead of a customized ASIC.  Designing and manufacturing an ASIC can be extremely expensive; they really only make sense where either extreme performance is required or when there is enough volume to amortize the NRE of designing the ASIC.  For a low-volume product, FPGAs can be far more economical despite the higher unit cost.